# What orders of Ram Rise Coefficient (Recovery Factor) are commonly encountered?

Tags: aerodynamics, supersonic, aircraft-physics

The answer to the question about [OAT, RAT, TAT, and SAT](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1640/what-is-the-difference-between-oat-rat-tat-and-sat/1642#1642) has the following:

> Problem is, not all instruments will compress that air in the same way, and not all of them will pick up this Ram Rise entirely. So they will publish a K, a ram-rise-coefficient (also called recovery factor) meaning how much of from the theoretical Ram Rise they actually pick up.

It appears for speeds exceeding 1.5 Mach, Ram Rise starts achieving oppressive values. At 1.6 Mach, and -25C SAT we're already dealing with temperature rise to above 100C. The only "redeeming factor" is K, which may prevent such rapid and drastic rise for a short while.

What orders of magnitude does *K* appear in, in typical scenarios where ram rise starts playing a role - a supersonic fighter, a missile, a rocket?