# Ram Rise and Total Air Temperature explantation

Tags: aerodynamics

Since ram rise is the same as total air temperature, why does Total Air Temperature minus Static Air Temperature give ram rise? What is really the meaning of ram rise: is it the kinetic components acting on an aircraft, or what?

Comment: Does [this question and its answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1640/7532) give you what you're looking for?

Comment: Hint: the opening statement "Since ram rise ***is the same as*** total air temperature..." is incorrect.  The addition you mention, SAT+RR = TAT, is explained in the answer I linked, and that's what you should focus on there.